# Kotlin retrofit convert JSON object to Kotlin Object

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit

I have data from an API that looks like this

```
{"post code": "45219", "country": "United States", "country abbreviation": "US", "places": [{"place name": "Cincinnati", "longitude": "-84.5131", "state": "Ohio", "state abbreviation": "OH", "latitude": "39.127"}]}
```

Using Retrofit I try to convert it to an object using the below code. For testing it is currently being fed a static variable as a zip code that is known to work.

---

Service Class.

```
class AddressService {

fun fetchCityAndState(zipCode : String) : MutableLiveData<Address>{
    var _addresses = MutableLiveData<Address>()
    val service = RetroFitClientInstance.retrofitInstace?.create(IAddressDAO::class.java)
    val call = service?.getLocation("https://api.zippopotam.us/us/$zipCode")
    call?.enqueue(object: Callback<Address> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Address>, t: Throwable) {
            print("Could not retrieve service response")
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Address>, response: Response<Address>) {
            _addresses.value = response.body()
        }
    })
    return _addresses
}
```

Address Class

```
data class Address(@SerializedName("post code") var postCode: String, @SerializedName("country") var country: String, @SerializedName("country abbreviation") var countryAbbreviation: String, @SerializedName("places") var placeInformation: ArrayList<Location>)
```

Location Class

```
class Location (@SerializedName("place name") var name: String, @SerializedName("longitude") var longitude: String, @SerializedName("state") var state: String, @SerializedName("state abbreviation") var stateAbbreviation: String, @SerializedName("latitude") var latitude: String)
```

Address Interface

```
@GET
fun getLocation(@Url zipCodeUrl:String) : Call<Address>
```

---

When using the debugger I see the call skip over the onFailure and onResponse functions and just return _addresses still empty. I even put print statements in both functions and  neither showed up in the terminal to confirm neither function is being run. There are no errors in the terminal when it happens.

EDIT 1

Retrofit client instance

```
object RetroFitClientInstance {

private var retrofit : Retrofit? = null
private var BASE_URL = "https://api.zippopotam.us"

val retrofitInstace : Retrofit?
    get() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        }
        return retrofit
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will see the change where you have observed this live data.

onResponse or onFailure won't called instantly because there are async calls try to add break point in onResponse block and onFailure block

also add break point where you are observing this live data

```
fetchCityAndState().observe(viewLifecycleOwner,youObserver {

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured retrofit properly? Share the code or make sure that you pass okhttpclient and converter (usually it's gson converter)

Comment: I believe so, I have added the file to the question.